# putting the results file on a remote server not working

Tags: powershell

<sup>**Editor's note**: The OP believes to have encountered a case where `Out-File -Append`, against expected behavior, does *not* create the target file on demand.

If this is indeed the case, it would be a *bug*.

There is no known reproducible case at this point.</sup>

The script runs fine but the file never shows up.  I have a share with the proper rights but nothing is showing up.  Please advise.

```
$machinename = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
$MachineFinalName = $machinename.Caption
$wsus = Get-Service -name wuauserv
    if ($wsus.Status -eq 'Stopped')
    {
         $MachineFinalName | Out-File -FilePath \\192.168.1.200\Service_Results\serviceoff.txt -Append

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to create the file in the server share and it works perfectly.

Comment: Generally, `Out-File -Append` should _automatically_ create the output file if it doesn't exist yet. Are you saying that that didn't happen in your case?

Comment: That is correct.  Once I created it, it then populated the data.

Comment: That would amount to a _bug_ in `Out-File`, so please note that in your answer, along with the specific PowerShell version you're using. If you have a reproducible case (personally, I can't reproduce it), If you have a reproducible case, I encourage you to report it at [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues), if the problem is reproducible in the latest version of _PowerShell Core_ or on [uservoice.com](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell), if it is reproducible  only in _Windows PowerShell_.

Comment: Thanks for the info @mklement0